# How to use Spring to connect to MongoDB which requires authentication

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am using the below Spring configuration in order to connect to mongoDB

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongodb.dbname}"/>
    </bean>


    <bean class="com.mongodb.MongoURI" id="mongoUri">
        <constructor-arg value="${mongodb.url}"  />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.mongodb.Mongo" id="mongo">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoUri" />
    </bean>
```

where `mongo.url=mongodb://<user>:<password>@<host>:27017`

However I'm getting an authetication error.
My understanding was that MongoUI can take a URL in the above format.

I know that mongoTemplate can accept userCredentials object however I would need to extract them from the URL first and i'm not sure how to do that in the configuration.

Any idea how can I change my config above to suppot this assuming mongo.url format cannot be changed?

Comment: Try shuffling the order of bean entries

Comment: uhu???? The order of the beans in a Spring configuration doesn't matter, that's basic Spring

Answer (score 22, accepted):

found the solution using Spring Expression Language

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongodb.dbname}"/>
        <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="mongoCredentials"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
        <property name="username" value="#{mongoURI.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{new java.lang.String(mongoURI.password)}" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.mongodb.MongoURI" id="mongoURI">
        <constructor-arg value="${mongodb.url}"  />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.mongodb.Mongo" id="mongo">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoURI" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: better to use `<constructor-arg ...` instead of `<property ...` in "mongoCredentials" bean description

Comment: it's for single MongoDB instance,not for Replica Set

Comment: Can you explain `#{mongoURI.username}` and `#{new java.lang.String(mongoURI.password)}`

Answer (score 14):

If you want to add authntication using java config

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("path.to.your.repository")
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration
{
@Value("${mongodb.name}")
private String  dbName;

@Value("${mongodb.host}")
private String  host;

@Value("${mongodb.port}")
private Integer port;

@Value("${mongodb.username}")
private String  userName;

@Value("${mongodb.password}")
private String  password;


@Override
protected String getDatabaseName()
{
    return this.dbName;
}

@Override
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception
{
    return new MongoClient(this.host, this.port);
}

@Override
@Bean
public SimpleMongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception
{
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo(), getDatabaseName());
}

@Override
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception
{
    final UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials(this.userName, this.password);

    final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongo(), getDatabaseName(), userCredentials);
    mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);

    return mongoTemplate;
}

}
```

Comment: Even easier now suffices to override the `getUserCredentials()` method. and remove the mongoTemplate and mongoDbFactory methods.

Comment: Two issues:

1) this code uses API s that are now deprecated.

2) the code can result in multiple different MongoClient objects getting created due to the "mongo()" call in the mongoDbFactory() where it should check if it's already created the object and not create another one.

Answer (score 8):

To update @Lealem Admassu's answer for java config, in Mongo 3 they changed the API, and now it is recommended to use mongo's `MongoCredentials` instead of `UserCredentials`.

Here there is a simple example of how to get a MongoClient:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-3.authentication

The next code can be done modular, but more or less this works for me (I needed a MongoTemplate):

```
public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate(String host, int port,
                                      String authenticationDB,
                                      String database,
                                      String user, char[] password)
        throws UnknownHostException {
    return new MongoTemplate(
            new SimpleMongoDbFactory(
                    new MongoClient(
                            new ServerAddress(host, port),
                            Collections.singletonList(
                                    MongoCredential.createCredential(
                                            user,
                                            authenticationDB,
                                            password
                                    )
                            )
                    ),
                    database
            )
    );
}
```