# How to connect spring mvc with mongodb database

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am new to mongodb and spring mvc.I want to know about  how to connect spring mvc with mongodb database.Any suggestions would be nice.Thanks in advance!

Comment: [use this link better google it first before posting this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10282271/2749470) and [this link too will be help ful](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-connectors)

Answer (score 0):

It has been explained in the docs. Follow http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-connectors.