# Spring Data MongoDB Replica Set UserCredentials Config?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

if i set Application can read from Secondary member of MongoDB Replica Set,and ecah member of Set need auth to access,how can i set each UserCredentials of Replicat Member?
My MongoDB config with Spring Data MongoDB as follow:

```
<mongo:mongo id="replicaSetMongo"
    replica-set="10.10.10.139:27017,10.10.10.139:27018,10.10.10.139:27019">
    <mongo:options connections-per-host="8"
        threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="4"
        connect-timeout="100000" max-wait-time="150000" auto-connect-retry="true"
        socket-keep-alive="true" socket-timeout="150000" slave-ok="false"
        write-number="1" write-timeout="0" write-fsync="true" />
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDBFactory" dbname="${mongo.db}"
    mongo-ref="replicaSetMongo" />

<mongo:template db-factory-ref="mongoDBFactory"
    write-concern="NORMAL" />


<mongo:mapping-converter db-factory-ref="mongoDBFactory"
    id="mongoDBConverter" />

<mongo:gridFsTemplate db-factory-ref="mongoDBFactory"
    converter-ref="mongoDBConverter" />
```

googled the article:https://scottizu.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/getting-started-with-spring-and-mongo-db/

but the credential must be the same for all set members?

Comment: Missed your point and thought you were asking how to copy the account credentials to each member. However, you don't set credentials for each member, it's just credentials for the connection. So nothing specific about a replica set.

Comment: thx,but if do not set credentials in xml,the application can not connect mongodb replica.

Comment: Possibly should be paying attention that there is [already an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249816/how-to-use-spring-to-connect-to-mongodb-which-requires-authentication) to setting the credentials.

Comment: I do not think so,i know how to set credential for single MongoDB instance,but if the primary member re-elected,how to assign the credential?

Comment: They all share the same credentials just like I said in the initial comment I made when I thought you were asking how to set up users on each replica set member. For the same reason the credentials are set on the connection, not per each replica set member. Just as you don't need to specify "all members" in the connection string, but it is a good idea to list more than one. Replication members are "discovered" by the driver. That is how it works. So one set of credentials for the connection. No different to using credentials for a single instance.

Comment: thanks  @NeilLunn but i follow the tutorial from MongoDB,http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-auth/  how can i set username/password based connection not database or node member?

Comment: Did you follow the examples in the duplicate question that is linked?

Comment: yes,i just change to Replica Set from Single MongoDB instance,and i set username/password for Database,and it's work in my application.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you are doing that does not work if you think it does not work. This has nothing to do with replica sets since there is no difference for authentication.

Comment: i need to set same username and password for all set members?

Comment: No you do not. Try it with all members marked in the collection. Edit your question to show your code that does not work. You are not following the examples correctly and doing it wrong. Commenting back is not helping you.